# Is Quickbitcoins.net gone with all money?

Tags: services

Site is down, google finds no new address. Can find nothingness on bitcoin forums, but Gregor not brightest crayon, perhaps doesn't know how to search.

Answer (score 1):

The site was shut down in November and the former operator [claims](http://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=78556.msg1324903#msg1324903) to no longer be involved with the service.

That operator is now attempting to raise funds for a new venture, [Ziggap](http://ziggap.com).

QuickBitcoins didn't take deposits.  They were a service used to buy coins for immediate delivery or for selling coins with immediate cash-out.

If you are owed bitcoins or funds from a cash-out transaction, the operator at the time would still be responsible for that liability, regardless of whatever disclaimer is provided about now "no longer having any relationship" with the service.